# Cannot read List with Gson afer writing

Tags: android, gson

I want to save and read `List<MyObj>` to sharedPreferences using `Gson`.

This is my write method:

```
private static final String GAS_STATIONS_LIST_KEY = "gasStationsListKey";

@Override
public void save(@NonNull List<MyObj> gasStations) {
    saveStr(GAS_STATIONS_LIST_KEY, gson.toJson(gasStations));
}

 private void saveStr(@NonNull String key, @Nullable String value) {
        sharedPreferences
                .edit()
                .putString(key, value)
                .apply();
    }
```

And this is my read method:

```
@Override
public List<MyObj> getGasStationList() {
    final Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyObj>>() {
    }.getClass();
    final List<MyObj> gasStations = gson.fromJson(GAS_STATIONS_LIST_KEY, type); // here null
    if (gasStations != null && !gasStations.isEmpty()) {
        return gasStations;
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

But when I try read data I get null (comment in last code part).

**How to fix it?**

Comment: what is GAS_STATIONS_LIST_KEY?

Comment: @Pravin update question

Comment: You are not getting the saved json content from shared prefences. you are trying to deserialize the key to a list, not the json content which is saved with that key

Comment: @DevrimTuncer update code - I save string

Comment: Yes I see, but where do you get that json string?

Comment: @DevrimTuncer generate using Gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the saved json content from shared prefences. You are trying to deserialize the key to a list, not the json content which is saved with that key.

Change this:

```
final List<MyObj> gasStations = gson.fromJson(GAS_STATIONS_LIST_KEY, type);
```

To this:

```
String savedJsonContent =  sharedPreferences.getString(GAS_STATIONS_LIST_KEY, null);
final List<MyObj> gasStations = gson.fromJson(savedJsonContent , type);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` only store primitive data Types.

Comment: yes, Gson give me String from List<MyObj> and I save this string

Comment: yes but he is storing string, which is a primitive type too.